# Connecting to MySQL database on Google Cloud with Node.js (Error: connect ENOENT)

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL database on Google Cloud through my app hosted in the same project as the database. The app is written in node.js.

This is my code:

```
    mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    password: "{root password}",
    database: "{database}",
    socketPath: "{project-id}:europe-west1:{database-name}",
    multipleStatements: true
});
```

The app is successfully deployed, but whenever I visit a page that uses MySQL, I get this error:

```
    { Error: connect ENOENT {project-id}:europe-west1:{database-name}      at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)      at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)      at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      --------------------
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:54:12)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]    code: 'ENOENT',
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]    syscall: 'connect',
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]    address: '{project-id}:europe-west1:{database-name}',
2018-05-20 11:24:12 default[20180520t111014]    fatal: true }
```

And in the web browser, I get a 502 error.

This is my app.yaml

```
    runtime: nodejs
env: flex

beta_settings:
  # The connection name of your instance, available by using
  # 'gcloud beta sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]' or from
  # the Instance details page in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
  cloud_sql_instances: {project-id}:europe-west1:{database-name}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end? I'm having literally the same problem and I'm determined to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

socketPath should be:

```
socketPath: "/cloudsql/{project-id}:europe-west1:{database}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update beta_settings in your app.yaml file.

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: {project-id}:europe-west1:{database-name}
```