# I can't connect gcloud mysql with app engine using express js application

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, gcloud, node-mysql

I'm trying to deploy my express js application to app engine, Also I want to link this app engine to the mysql database but I get this error when connection to database :

```
Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/********3li      at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1145:16)
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]      --------------------
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]      at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]      at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]      at PoolConnection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]      at Pool.getConnection (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]      at Pool.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]      at /app/api/routes/users.js:48:22
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]    errno: 'ENOENT',
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]    code: 'ENOENT',
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]    syscall: 'connect',
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]    address: '/cloudsql/********3li ',
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]    fatal: true
2021-10-15 08:46:41 appengineedokanapi[20211015t103941]  }
```

I'm also using node-mysql library with express js

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    socketPath: `/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`,
})
```

app.yaml contains:

```
env_variables: 
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME : ********3li
  DB_DATABASE : databaseName
  DB_USER : databaseUser
  DB_PASSWORD : *******
```

Comment: If credentials are correct, are you sure it's not blocked by firewall your connection? MySQL is quite specific to wildcards or designated connections.

Comment: @blanknamefornow Hi, My credentials are correct. I think all apps in the same project are authorized by default or you meant another thing ?

Comment: MySQL is not listening for your connection returning an error at your client side. The fix is having MySQL listen for this app some how. Could be firewall on MySQL allowing specific connections and this app isn't one, user in MySQL isn't configured correctly or few others but the issue points to MySQL not listening for your app.

Comment: Some searching though, maybe your socketPath is incorrect, few posts would suggest it possibly.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434036/connecting-to-mysql-database-on-google-cloud-with-node-js-error-connect-enoent

Comment: Check is `/cloudsql/********3li` exists, and node process can read/write to it. eg by `mysql -u root -p -S /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock/fix/yourself/socket/path`

Comment: Does you `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` is the correct one? Are you just writing the name of the instance or the complete connection name which has the form `{project-id}:europe-west1:{database}` as the link shared by @blanknamefornow

Comment: Yes, the problem was at connection name which has the form {project-id}:europe-west1:{database}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by 'blacknamefornow' in a comment and confirmed by mohamed-ali, the problem was in the `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` env variable in the `app.yaml` file.

Referenced from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50436165/4905518) answer, the format should be `{project-id}:europe-west1:{database}`.